# Angular- supporting both hash & normal url?

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to Angularjs, so please excuse me if that's an obvious question.
We have an existing Ajgularjs single-page application, that works with data from after the hash. E.g.

```
http://server/myapp#/user/777?accountid=123&arranger=true
```

Note the hash.

This usually works. Unfortunately we ran into some new scenario where we can't use hash (the deep link sometimes goes through an authentication framework outside our control, and it strips down the hash portion of the url). So we also need links without a hash, e.g.

```
http://server/myapp/user/777?accountid=123&arranger=true
```

Note : I don't mind the exact format, just note it is hash-free.

The question: is there some reasonable way to support both approaches, so that the application would react similarly to both types of link? (we need the "hash" format for backwards compatibility with old links, and we need the "hash less" format for the new authentication scenario)

thanks very much

Comment: I think, this is a perfectly valid question with a very good real world scenario. @Amstell just wondering, what did you see bad about it ?

Comment: shouldn't [html5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`) solve it?

Comment: Amstell & Rabi, thanks a lot for your feedbacks, indeed I made a few edits due to lack of experience with code formatting - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

On the [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service, angular makes all parts of the url available to the application.

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"

// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var path = $location.path();
// => "/some/path"

// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo#hashValue
var hash = $location.hash();
// => "hashValue"
```

I'm not sure what your particular situation is, but you might be able to use a `$routeChangeStart` event handler (or `$stateChangeStart` if using ui-router) to intercept the route and use an appropriate method on `$location` to figure out what route you would like to go to. Then set the url to navigate to the decoded route in the application.